# Insightly API with filter

Tags: api, curl, insightly

I have created a cUrl to get a filtered list of contacts. Regardless of me passing the filter items I always get ALL of the contacts. Here is the curl:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Basic <MY API KEY>" https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/contacts?filter=LAST_NAME='Jones'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter like this

https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/contacts?$filter=LAST_NAME%20eq%20'Jones'